# Influx write api catch exceptions

Tags: java, influxdb

## Context

I have a project which uses `influxdb-client-java` version `7.0.0`. I am writing points using the `WriteApi` which starts a background thread to send data to the influxdb instance.

## My Problem

I want to catch the `UnauthorizedException` to act upon it.

## Question

Can I register an exception handler somewhere or how could I achive that?

I have searched online but could not find any useful documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way how to achieve it. The `WriteApi` has a `listenEvents` method which you can use for it. An example:

```
final var writeApi = client.makeWriteApi(writeOptions);
     writeApi.listenEvents(WriteErrorEvent.class, event -> {
     if (event.getThrowable() instanceof UnauthorizedException) {
          log.error("Could not send data to influx. The provided influx token is either wrong or does not has the write permission granted.");
          System.exit(-1);
     }
});
```